# Why does Solve work and NSolve hang?

Tags: equation-solving

My computer can solve this quickly.

```
Solve[{x + y + z + u + v == 2, p x + q y + r z + s u + t v == 3, 
  p^2 x + q^2 y + r^2 z + s^2 u + t^2 v == 16, 
  p^3 x + q^3 y + r^3 z + s^3 u + t^3 v == 31, 
  p^4 x + q^4 y + r^4 z + s^4 u + t^4 v == 103, 
  p^5 x + q^5 y + r^5 z + s^5 u + t^5 v == 235, 
  p^6 x + q^6 y + r^6 z + s^6 u + t^6 v == 674, 
  p^7 x + q^7 y + r^7 z + s^7 u + t^7 v == 1669, 
  p^8 x + q^8 y + r^8 z + s^8 u + t^8 v == 4526, 
  p^9 x + q^9 y + r^9 z + s^9 u + t^9 v == 11595}, {p, q, r, s, t, u, 
  v, x, y, z}]
```

but when I use `NSolve`

```
NSolve[{x + y + z + u + v == 2, p x + q y + r z + s u + t v == 3, 
  p^2 x + q^2 y + r^2 z + s^2 u + t^2 v == 16, 
  p^3 x + q^3 y + r^3 z + s^3 u + t^3 v == 31, 
  p^4 x + q^4 y + r^4 z + s^4 u + t^4 v == 103, 
  p^5 x + q^5 y + r^5 z + s^5 u + t^5 v == 235, 
  p^6 x + q^6 y + r^6 z + s^6 u + t^6 v == 674, 
  p^7 x + q^7 y + r^7 z + s^7 u + t^7 v == 1669, 
  p^8 x + q^8 y + r^8 z + s^8 u + t^8 v == 4526, 
  p^9 x + q^9 y + r^9 z + s^9 u + t^9 v == 11595}, {p, q, r, s, t, u, 
  v, x, y, z}]
```

Warning: your computer may stuck.Even shut down.

Why? Since numerical calculation seems should quicker than symbolic calculation.

After testing on several versions. I get some thing. 12.0 stuck ,11.3 stuck. 11.2 run smoothly, 8.0 run smoothly. So there maybe something with version or the changes of internal algorithm.

Comment: After testing on several versions. I get some thing. 12.0 stuck ,11.3 stuck. 11.2 run smoothly, 8.0 run smoothly. So there maybe something with version or the changes of internal algorithm.

Comment: You can edit your question to include the new observation.

Comment: Cool, it's the only time I've seen my CPU usage go up to nearly 800%. (It's never gone above 400% with *Mathematica*. Mac 4-core i7.)

Comment: Probably a change in default method used. Setting `Method->"EndomorphismMatrix"` brings it back to a feasible computation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Someone in the comment gives the solution.

just set the method like this.

```
NSolve[{x + y + z + u + v == 2, p x + q y + r z + s u + t v == 3, 
  p^2 x + q^2 y + r^2 z + s^2 u + t^2 v == 16, 
  p^3 x + q^3 y + r^3 z + s^3 u + t^3 v == 31, 
  p^4 x + q^4 y + r^4 z + s^4 u + t^4 v == 103, 
  p^5 x + q^5 y + r^5 z + s^5 u + t^5 v == 235, 
  p^6 x + q^6 y + r^6 z + s^6 u + t^6 v == 674, 
  p^7 x + q^7 y + r^7 z + s^7 u + t^7 v == 1669, 
  p^8 x + q^8 y + r^8 z + s^8 u + t^8 v == 4526, 
  p^9 x + q^9 y + r^9 z + s^9 u + t^9 v == 11595}, {p, q, r, s, t, u, 
  v, x, y, z}, Method -> "EndomorphismMatrix"]
```

all will be ok.

Since I don't know how to accept a comment.I have to answer it myself.

Comment: Related discussion in meta: https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1876/1871